# How to associate columns that aren't directly associated?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data:

```
label    ui     dc          mapId

1        209459 50580-590   1      
1        198440 50580-590   2      

2        209459 50580-449   3      
2        198440 50580-449   4      

3        198440 43353-066   5      
3        198440 43353-067   6      
3        198440 43353-059   7           

4        187878 89999-876   8
```

Which im inserting and mapping it with this query using the `label` column:

```
DECLARE @dc TABLE (label int, dc varchar(50))
DECLARE @ui TABLE (label int, ui varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @DC
VALUES (1, '50580-590'), (2, '50580-449'), (3, '43353-066'), (3, '43353-067'), (3, '43354-059'), (4, '89999-876')

INSERT INTO @UI
VALUES (1, '209459'), (1, '198440'), (2, '209459'), (2, '198440'), (3, '198440'), (4, '187878')

SELECT *
FROM @dc A
INNER JOIN (    
    SELECT *
    FROM @ui
    ) B
ON A.label = B.label
```

Im trying to find the rows that are in a way associated to each other. For example, I want to look for rows where `dc = 43353-059` and the ui that is associated to that row which would be the row where `mapId = 7`. In that row the `ui = 198440` so after I do that I want to look for the rows where ui is 198440  but then I want to look at the label. If you take row where `mapId = 2`, ui with `198440` has `label of 1 but on mapId 1 ui of 209459` is also associated with `label of 1`. In that way you could say that `mapId 1 - 7` are related. Using that logic im trying to make a query using the data at the top and get this result:

```
label    ui     dc          masterId

1        209459 50580-590   1
1        198440 50580-590   2

3        209459 50580-449   3
3        198440 50580-449   4

3        198440 43353-066   5
3        198440 43353-067   6
3        198440 43353-059   7

4        187878 89999-876   1
```

Since i cant in any way relate the mapId 8 to the other rows I start over from 1 on the masterId column. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did your get Map ID and Master ID ?

Comment: @Avi MapId would just be the number of the row. Only added it to easily point to the rows in the example and the master id is to show how the result of the query i need should come out, not part of the original data

Comment: What version of SQL Server? By any chance 2017+?

Comment: @VitalyBorisov I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using Vitaly's answer, but applying Unpivot two more times to find all the related labels and then condensing them like he did:

```
DECLARE @dc TABLE (label int, dc varchar(50))
DECLARE @ui TABLE (label int, ui varchar(50))
DECLARE @RelatedLabel TABLE (Label int, [group] int)
DECLARE @Crossings TABLE (Label INT,Value INT)
DECLARE @Crossings2 TABLE (Label INT, Value INT)
DECLARE @RelatedLabel2 TABLE (Label int, Value int)
DECLARE @Result TABLE (Label INT, dc varchar(50), ui varchar(50), seqnum int, masterId int)

INSERT INTO @DC
VALUES (1, '50580-590'), (2, '50580-449'), (3, '43353-066'), (3, '43353-067'), (3, '43354-059'), (4, '89999-876')
, (5, '88888-90')

INSERT INTO @UI
VALUES (1, '209459'), (1, '198440'), (2, '209459'), (2, '198440'), (3, '198440'), (4, '187878')
, (5, '187878'), (5, '209459')

INSERT INTO @Crossings(label,[Value])
SELECT DISTINCT up.Label,up.Value
FROM (
    SELECT dc.label AS [Label],dc.RelatedLabel AS [1],ui.label AS [2],ui.RelatedLabel AS [3]
    FROM (
        SELECT dc.label,dc2.label AS [RelatedLabel]
        FROM @dc dc
        LEFT JOIN @dc dc2 ON dc2.dc = dc.dc
    ) dc
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ui.label,ui2.label AS [RelatedLabel]
        FROM @ui ui
        LEFT JOIN @ui ui2 On ui2.ui = ui.ui
    ) ui ON ui.label = dc.label OR ui.label = dc.RelatedLabel OR ui.RelatedLabel = dc.RelatedLabel OR ui.RelatedLabel = dc.label
) a
UNPIVOT(Value FOR Param IN ([1],[2],[3])) up
ORDER BY up.label
;

INSERT INTO @RelatedLabel
SELECT DISTINCT g.label,g2.label AS [RelatedLabel]
    FROM @Crossings g
    LEFT JOIN @Crossings g2 ON (g2.[Value] = g.[label] OR g2.[label] = g.[Value])

INSERT INTO @RelatedLabel2
SELECT distinct A.Label as Label, B.label AS [1]
FROM @RelatedLabel A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM @RelatedLabel
    ) B
ON A.[group] = b.[group] OR A.label = B.[group]

INSERT INTO @Crossings2
SELECT distinct A.Label as Label, B.label AS [1]
FROM @RelatedLabel2 A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM @RelatedLabel2
    ) B
ON A.value = b.value OR A.label = B.value

DECLARE @Group TABLE (Label INT,TheGroup VARCHAR(255))
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT g.label,g2.label AS [RelatedLabel]
    FROM @Crossings2 g
    LEFT JOIN @Crossings2 g2 ON (g2.[Value] = g.[label] OR g2.[label] = g.[Value])
)
INSERT INTO @Group(Label,TheGroup)
SELECT DISTINCT d.Label
    ,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),r.RelatedLabel) FROM cte r WHERE r.Label = d.Label ORDER BY 1 FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS [TheGroup]
FROM cte d
;


SELECT dc.label,dc.dc,ui.ui
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY g.TheGroup ORDER BY dc.label) AS seqnum
FROM @dc dc
INNER JOIN @ui ui ON ui.label = dc.label
INNER JOIN @Group g ON g.Label = dc.label
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look

```
DECLARE @Crossings TABLE (Label INT,Value INT)
INSERT INTO @Crossings(label,[Value])
SELECT DISTINCT up.Label,up.Value
FROM (
    SELECT dc.label AS [Label],dc.RelatedLabel AS [1],ui.label AS [2],ui.RelatedLabel AS [3]
    FROM (
        SELECT dc.label,dc2.label AS [RelatedLabel]
        FROM @dc dc
        LEFT JOIN @dc dc2 ON dc2.dc = dc.dc
    ) dc
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT ui.label,ui2.label AS [RelatedLabel]
        FROM @ui ui
        LEFT JOIN @ui ui2 On ui2.ui = ui.ui
    ) ui ON ui.label = dc.label OR ui.label = dc.RelatedLabel OR ui.RelatedLabel = dc.RelatedLabel
) a
UNPIVOT(Value FOR Param IN ([1],[2],[3])) up
ORDER BY up.label
;

DECLARE @Group TABLE (Label INT,TheGroup NVARCHAR(255))
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT g.label,g2.label AS [RelatedLabel]
    FROM @Crossings g
    LEFT JOIN @Crossings g2 ON (g2.[Value] = g.[label] OR g2.[label] = g.[Value])
)
INSERT INTO @Group(Label,TheGroup)
SELECT DISTINCT d.Label
    ,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(50),r.RelatedLabel) FROM cte r WHERE r.Label = d.Label ORDER BY 1 FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS [TheGroup]
FROM cte d
;


SELECT dc.label,dc.dc,ui.ui
    ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS [MapId]
    ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY g.TheGroup ORDER BY dc.label) AS [MasterId]
FROM @dc dc
INNER JOIN @ui ui ON ui.label = dc.label
INNER JOIN @Group g ON g.Label = dc.label
;
```

Comment: While that works for the data that i provided, it doesn't work if lets say i changed in mapId 8, dc = 43353-059. In that case, since theres already a row that has dc = 43353-059 which is mapId 7, it would relate the row to the rest of the rows and `masterId = 8`. If i was to add another row to the original data where `ui = 209459`, `dc = 89999-876` and `label = 5` and mapId = 9, then mapId 1 - 9 would all be related since im trying to relate `label` with `dc` and `ui`  Let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: Ah, I thought matches are only on labels and uis. It should be on DC too then. All right.

Comment: Totally rewrote answer - no more funky "power functions". Please try.

Comment: I tried adding another `label` like so: ```INSERT INTO @DC
VALUES (1, '50580-590'), (2, '50580-449'), (3, '43353-066'), (3, '43353-067'), (3, '43354-059'), (4, '43353-067'), (5, '89999-876')

INSERT INTO @UI
VALUES (1, '209459'), (1, '198440'), (2, '209459'), (2, '198440'), (3, '198440'), (4, '187878'), (5, '187878')```, but it didnt get it right

Comment: I think it has to be two recursions then - up and down, to find all dependencies

Comment: Yea, that makes sense

Comment: Was able to get it working by doing what you said, applied Unpivot two more times to the declared table @Crossings and then used the cte to condense the related labels.

Comment: Could you please post  your solution as an answer to your own question - I'd like to see how it's done too.

Answer (score -1):

ROW_NUMBER modulus 7?

```sql
DECLARE @dc TABLE (label int, dc varchar(50))
DECLARE @ui TABLE (label int, ui varchar(50))

INSERT INTO @DC
VALUES (1, '50580-590'), (2, '50580-449'), (3, '43353-066'), (3, '43353-067'), (3, '43354-059'), (4, '89999-876')

INSERT INTO @UI
VALUES (1, '209459'), (1, '198440'), (2, '209459'), (2, '198440'), (3, '198440'), (4, '187878')

SELECT 
  A.label
  , B.ui
  , A.dc
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.label, b.ui DESC, a.dc DESC) AS mapId
  , CASE 
      WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.label, b.ui DESC, a.dc DESC) % 7 = 0 THEN 7 
      ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.label, b.ui DESC, a.dc DESC) % 7 
    END masterId
FROM @dc A
INNER JOIN (    
    SELECT *
    FROM @ui
    ) B
ON A.label = B.label
```

[ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
[% (Modulus) (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)